# Como añadir simbolos entre numeros usando expresiones regulares

Tags: python

Digamos que tengo una secuencia de numeros:

```
146546644545454
```

Y quiero añadir símbolos entre cada numero ej:

```
1%//////%%2%//////%%6... así con todos mis numeros
```

Estos numeros los tendré guardados en un fichero con diferentes carácteres. Como puedo hacer para que cuando sea un numero le añada delante estos símbolos usando expresiones regulares??? Por lo que lo que estaba intentando era en un fichero con extension rtf y usando expresiones regulares añadir símbolos entre los numeros. Y hacerlo desde este fichero no como cadena de texto.

Comment: xD RTF ofuscado malicioso?

Comment: xD!  Oh si. Nada que ver  CVE-2012-0158? https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Malicious+RTF+Files/21315/ xD xD sólo anidando un HTA que se ejecuta vía OLE2 sin avisar y que casualmente descarga un troyano, todo eso en una cadena de shellcode hexadecimal que se anida en las estructuras recursivas de el RTF malformado? O solo es casualidad?

Comment: Yo nomás decía, por aquí más de uno reconoce shellcode cuando lo ven, y estás haciendo todas las preguntas correctas! Necesitas firmar un binario, (te faltan certificados y si los firmas tú mismo no sirven por cierto), Kali Linux, deofuscar un payload de VBA con comandos de powershell. Etc. Vas por el camino correcto, solo se honesto. =)

Comment: Nah no es que hayas preguntado algo incorrecto o inapropiadio, la información y el conocimiento quieren ser libres, y preguntar es la mejor forma de aprender, siempre y cuando seas honesto. Es muy obvio que quieres replicar un las técnicas de un exploit reciente. Hay 2 tipos de gente con interés en  regex complejos los q hacen flujos ETL para migrar datos y los que quieren evitar detección heurística y sembrar troyanos en máquinas vulnerables. Solo hay que ser honestos. En mi adolescencia el malware si era interesante. Brain, st0ned, etc en diskettes de 5 1/4 para cargarlos en una PC XT 80286

Comment: No era esa mi intención el codigo lo saque de internet y no es mio no sabía que bajaba un hta y nada más. No saltaré la heurística ni sembraré tal cosa. Nada más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> texto = "1abc46546644545454"
>>> salida = re.sub(r'([0-9])', r"\1%//////%%", texto)
>>> print(salida)
1%//////%%abc4%//////%%6%//////%%5%//////%%4%//////%%6%//////%%6%//////%%4%//////%%4%//////%%5%//////%%4%//////%%5%//////%%4%//////%%5%//////%%4%//////%%
```

Con `[0-9]` capturamos cada dígito, con `([0-9])` indicamos que cada uno constituya un grupo de forma que podemos hacer referencia a el con `\1` en el patrón de sustitución (`r"\1%//////%%"`).

> **Nota:** Esto añade la cadena "%//////%%" a continuación de cualquier carácter en el rango 0-9 sin importarle nada más que encuentre en el texto.

---

---

**Edición 1:**

Si quieres hacer esto con un archivo puedes hacer los siguiente si quieres substituir el archivo original:

```
with open("ola.rtf", 'r+') as f:
    texto = re.sub(r'([0-9])', r"\1%//////%%", f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(texto)
    f.truncate()
```

o si quieres crear un nuevo archivo y mantener al anterior:

```
with open('ola.rtf', 'r') as f_in, open('ola_out.rtf', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(re.sub(r'([0-9])', r"\1%//////%%", f_in.read()))
```

---

**Edición 2:**

Para aplicar `re.sub` a solo parte del documento se puede usar `readlines` que retorna una lista con las lineas del archivo. Luego aplicamos `re.sub` a las filas que queramos y escribimos en el fichero de salida:

```
with open('ola.rtf', 'r') as f_in, open('ola_out.rtf', 'w') as f_out:
    lineas = f_in.readlines()
    sub_text = re.sub(r'([0-9])', r"\1%//////%%", "".join(lineas[15:]))
    f_out.writelines(lineas[:15])
    f_out.write(sub_text)
```

Esto aplica `re.sub` desde la linea 15 hasta el final. Tener en cuenta que **las lineas se empiezan a numerar desde 0**, no desde 1. Si empezamos a numerar desde 1 tendremos que cambiar `lineas[15:]` y  `lineas[:15]` por `lineas[14:]` y  `lineas[:14]`.

Si queremos modificar unas lineas determinadas podemos hacer algo como:

```
lineas = [1, 2, 15, 16] 
with open('ola.rtf', 'r') as f_in, open('ola_out.rtf', 'w') as f_out:
    patt = re.compile(r'([0-9])')
    texto = f_in.readlines()
    for i in lineas:
        texto[i] = re.sub(patt, r"\1%//////%%", texto[i])
    f_out.writelines(texto)
```

Con esto aplicamos `re.sub` a las lineas 1, 2, 15 y 16 (recordar que la primera linea es la 0). No se aplica ningún mecanismo de control de excepciones, implementar de ser necesario. Si se da un indice que mayor al numero de lineas del documento obtendremos una excepción por indice fuera de rango.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo la unica pregunta que tendría es si fuera un fichero (quiero remplazar el texto de este fichero) sería asi? 
for line in open(r'file.txt'): salida = re.sub(r'([0-9])', r"\1%//////%%", line) y escribo el fichero algo así?

Comment: muchas gracias amigo es la respuesta ideal.

Comment: @TecnologyNow editada la respuesta intentando responder a tu última duda, mira al final de esta ver que tal.